# How to disable react-facebook-login pop-up?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to make a simple react web apps with facebook auth for login and the authorization using react-facebook-login from the npmjs package, but it's always blocked by a popup-blocker. My code is thus:

```js
  static defaultProps = {
    textButton: 'Login with Facebook',
    scope: 'public_profile, email',
    xfbml: false,
    cookie: false,
    size: 'metro',
    fields: 'name',
    cssClass: 'kep-login-facebook',
    version: '2.3',
    language: 'en_US',
    uri: encodeURI('http://myapps.com');
  };

    document.body.appendChild(fbRoot);

    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: this.props.appId,
        xfbml: this.props.xfbml,
        cookie: this.props.cookie,
        version: 'v' + this.props.version,
      });

      if (this.props.autoLoad) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(this.checkLoginState);
      }
    };

    ((d, s, id) => {
      const element = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      const fjs = element;
      let js = element;
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/' + this.props.language + '/all.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }

  responseApi = (authResponse) => {
    FB.api('/me', { fields: this.props.fields }, (me) => {
      Object.assign(me, authResponse)
      this.props.callback(me);
    });
  };

  checkLoginState = (response) => {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      this.responseApi(response.authResponse);
    } else {
      if (this.props.callback) {
        this.props.callback({ status: response.status });
      }
    }
  };

  click = () => {
    FB.login(this.checkLoginState, { scope: this.props.scope });
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where exactly are you using a "react-facebook-login" plugin? looks like basic js sdk to me. or is that actually the code of the plugin? what´s important is YOUR code then.

Comment: either way, there is only one reason i know why browsers would block the login, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers usually block the login popup when you try to call it in an asynchronous callback function. You MUST call it directly on user interaction (mouse click). I assume you don´t call the "click" function directly on user interaction.

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/